# What is name of structure Being + v3

Tags: grammar, tense, syntax

> I went to the hospital and I saw a patient **being treated** last night.

What kind of sentence it is **being treated** in the above sentence.

Comment: I'm sure there's some technical nomenclature distinguishing it from the semantically equivalent *...a patient **who was** being treated...*, but would [participle phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) satisfy you?

Comment: Note that "being treated" is not a sentence. The sentence is the entire example.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "being treated" includes a form of the verb *to be* followed by something that's traditionally called a *past participle*, which you're calling *v3*.   This is a passive voice construction, similar to constructions like "was treated", "is treated" and "will be treated".

The form of the verb *to be* that's used here is the *-ing form*.   Traditionally, *-ing* forms are labeled as either *gerunds* or *present participles*, depending on their use.   Some modern grammars call this the *gerund-participle* form, since the form is the same regardless of its use.

Different frameworks use different labels to describe the same thing.   Depending on framework, the phrase "being treated" in this sentence might be labeled as a *passive present participial phrase*, a *passive continuous participial phrase*, or even (I suspect) a *passive non-finite clause*.

No matter what label you choose, you're looking at a non-finite verb construction that has no tense, but that has the passive voice and the continuous aspect.

Comment: Please would you tell me more elaborated way. Actually didn not get. What is this structure actual called

Comment: according to you it is either gerund or present  participle but they both used v+ing only but in my above sentence they used v+ing + v3.

Comment: Well, yes.  You have a phrase that contains two words.  Each word deserves a label on its own, and the structure deserves a label.  Using traditional labels, "being" is a present participle form, "treated" is a past participle form, and "being treated" is a passive present participial phrase.  Using your abbreviations, "being" is *v-ing*, "treated" is *v3*, and you still have a structure that expresses the passive voice and continuous aspect.  If you don't like *passive continuous participial phrase* as a label, what label would you like?

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan hello, it is interesting theme of discussing. And I have another one sentence: `Yet despite his fear of being killed`. What can you say about it? What kind of construction is it? I am thinking that it is gerund, not passive voice.